# JavaFX opposite function of .requestFocus()?

Tags: javafx, focus

I'm looking for function in JavaFX, where I can "disable or dismiss" the requested focus.

Here is a screenshot of my program: [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ncm8jgz7j2bz7dj/Dienstplan.JPG)

Every cell is filled with an Eventhandler (onMouseEntered and onMouseExited) and in every onMouseEntered function I have to request the focus like this:
`label.requestFocus()`. I need to do that, because I'm using KeyEvents to change the content of the cell.

It works fine, but there is a bug: When I move out of the scrollPane, there is still the requested focus on the last entered cell.

How can I solve that issue, without requesting focus for everything around the Scrollpane to fix this bug? Is there a function, where I can dismiss the requested focus, so after exiting a cell, it'll dismiss the focus.

Best regards,

My code:

```
 arbeitetLabel.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

            arbeitetLabel.requestFocus();
            arbeitetLabel.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                    // Do some keyEvent Stuff
                }
            });


        }

    });

    arbeitetLabel.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            // Dismiss the requested Focus here?
        }

    });
```

Comment: Something has to have focus in the current window as far as I know. Why setting focus on the parent panel doesn't work?

Comment: Haha, great, it works! Thank you!
So I'm using that: `arbeitetLabel.getParent().requestFocus()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm passing the focus to the parent, that's it!

```
arbeitetLabel.getParent().requestFocus()
```